# How to write this query with this id?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add  this data-id   in query line

```
<li><a data-id="<?php echo $random_id;?>">Show</a></li>
```

In my case I can not add $random_id  here. I have to use the data-id.

simply I need to select from posts where id is equal to data-id.

How can I write  it down ?

```
$query = "select * from posts where id='???'  ";
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to get the data?

Comment: Why can't you use $random_id? Are you trying to refresh the page or use an ajax call?

Comment: No. should I use ajax ??

Comment: I am using it inside a modal ............there are more than 15 posts in one page ... so if I use $random_id  it will only get the first post .

Comment: why don't you use an href attribute? @Truespeaker

Comment: would you please tell me how to do the href to pass id to another  div ??@mith

Comment: You have many unmarked answers on your questions, therefore that will make us not to respond to your questions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this `data-id` attribute value in your php code directly. You have to use Jquery, Ajax to use this like:

```
var dataId = $('a').attr('data-id');
```

or

```
var dataId = $('a').data('id');
```

Now make an `ajax()` call and pass this value as an parameter in that call.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to make this happen - I believe - you have to use AJAX.

The code will look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your_script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {var1: javascript_var_1, var2: javascript_var_2},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
```

Your PHP will look similar to this (without keeping in mind the JSON encode:

```
<?php

$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];

$getvalue="SELECT id,name from table1 WHERE column1='$var1' and column2='$var2'";
 $result=mysql_query($getvalue) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   extract($row);
   echo $name;
 }
?>
```

Then you can JSON encode the results and pretty much output them on the success. Your php script - however - must live on another php file.

Also, escape your data. Use prepared statements.